# Android Studio Error : Unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.9.2)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on an Android Project for few months and I recently upgraded android studio form 0.5.2 to 0.8.0. Now I am unable to open my project via new Android Studio. I am getting this error whenever I try to open the project and unable to open it.

```
 The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.9.2)
 Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

I don't know much about Gradle, Ant, Maven or any built script. Also, there is no option to see the the logs from the Start screen of android studio.

Comment: The latest gradle plugin version is 0.12.+

Comment: Ok. So what changes to make and how do I make any changes, since I am unable to even open the project in Android Studio.

Comment: Am I the only one facing this problem after upgrading?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since your project is not being opened by the IDE, try to update Gradle plugin version manually. Locate `build.gradle` file in your project's root directory and change the version in `buildscript` block so it would look like this:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
```

Save the file and try to re-open your project.

Comment: I think it is also could require gradle 1.12 and java 1.7

Comment: This did not work for me. I am still having the 'you are using an unsupported version of gradle. Please use 1.10' error :( I am also using the Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.0... can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 0.8.7, you can change to

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}
```